# I want to change randomly through background colors in a more simpler manner (Pygame)

Tags: python, pygame

I want the change to randomly change through red and green at random times  In a easier way that doesnt involve the .wait function, (in seconds and fractions of seconds) right now I have

```
    self.time = random.randint(1,3)
    self.bgcolor = random.randint(1,2)
    if self.time == 1:
        self.x = 30
        self.wait = 1
    if self.time == 2:
        self.x = 30
        self.wait = 2
    if self.time == 3:      
        self.x = 30
        self.wait = 3
    if self.bgcolor == 1:   

        self.screen.fill(self.red)
        time.sleep(self.time)


        pygame.display.flip()



    if self.bgcolor == 2:
        self.screen.fill(self.green)
        time.sleep(self.time)


        pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make it something like:

```
from random import choice, randint

self.screen.fill(choice([self.red, self.green]))
self.wait = self.time = randint(1, 3)
time.sleep(self.wait)
```